# How long will my current session still last?

Tags: session, cakephp, timeout

1. How can I figure out when my current session will run out?
2. Is the session timeout updated on every request?

Answer (score 4):

You can find out the answer to the first question by looking in your configuration file in 'app/config/core.php'. It depends on how you've configured your setup. As for the second question, it will update on every page refresh. [Config File Info](http://book.cakephp.org/view/44/CakePHP-Core-Configuration-Variables)

Comment: // Actual value depends on 'Security.level' setting.
    Configure::write('Session.timeout', HOUR);

What does this mean to me?

Comment: The higher the level, the higher it will multiply your timeout value. More information here: http://book.cakephp.org/view/44/CakePHP-Core-Configuration-Variables

Comment: Yes. So if you set Session.timeout to 1000, then security will multiply that value depending on security. So, high = 1000x10, medium = 1000x100, low = 1000x300

Comment: No, sorry. My mistake, the lower your security. The longer your session will last. My mind completel died.

Comment: This means if I have Session.timeout set to HOUR/10 and Security.level to 'high' my session would last 1 hour?

Comment: Assuming HOUR is defined as 3600 seconds, and not the constant 60 for minutes.

Comment: ...updated on every page refresh. You have to do that manually... How??? Where, in app_controller.php, in which action?

Comment: Ok, HOUR is the cake constant with the value (int)3600

Comment: Just double checked, it will automatically update it for you. The behaviour was changed.